# Is there a standard color palettes for the spectral indices?

Tags: raster, ndvi

Is there a standard color palette (or most commonly used in publications and other materials) for the spectral indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard color palette for spectral indices. The most important is to represent the indices in a way that can understandable to someone looking at the map. Choosing a color palette is a matter of personal preference, some people prefer a range of strong tone with various (different) colors, others may prefer a range of same color (light to dark green), or a range of two colors (yellow/white to green, for example). It is recommended to choose a color that can be easily recognized on the map.

Here is some examples of NDVI color available at the web [Earth Observatory: NASA](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Experiments/ICE/panama/panama_ex2.php), [Tetracam](http://www.tetracam.com/Sample%20Imagery.htm), and [New NDVI colormap](https://publiclab.org/notes/cfastie/08-26-2014/new-ndvi-colormap)